# Callback in discord.py 2.0 not firing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an interaction roles system and my callbacks isn't working. I didn't get any errors from it. Here's the code I used:

```py
class IRRoleButton(discord.ui.Button["InteractionRoles"]):
        def __init__(self, role: discord.Role):
            super().__init__(style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, label=role.name, custom_id=role.id)
            # role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=id)
            self.role = role
        
        async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            print("wow")
            try:
                await interaction.user.add_roles(self.role)
                embed = discord.Embed(title="IR role added", description=f"You have been given the IR role {self.role.name}.", color=bot.success)
            except Exception as e:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Something went wrong", description=f"Contact the server administrator.", color=bot.error)
                print(e)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
    
class InteractionRoles(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, irroles: list):
        super().__init__()

        for button in irroles:
            role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=button["rid"])
            if role:
                self.add_item(IRRoleButton(role)) 

@apptree.command(description="Opens a public IR panel.", guild=discord.Object(id=956522017983725588))
@app_commands.describe(group="The ID of the group to open.")
async def iropen(interaction: discord.Interaction, group: int):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    group = await bot.db.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM irgroups WHERE grid = $1", group)
    if not group:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="IR group not found", description=f"An IR group with the ID `{group}` does not exist.", color=bot.error)
        return await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed) 
    
    irroles = await bot.db.fetch("SELECT * FROM irroles WHERE grid = $1", group["grid"])
    await interaction.channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=str(group['gname']), description="Press a button to get the corresponding role.", color=bot.accent), view=InteractionRoles(interaction, irroles))
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=discord.Embed(title="IR panel opened", description=f"The IR panel for {group['gname']} has been opened.", color=bot.success))
```

I know that callbacks isn't working because "wow" didn't print at all.

I'm using discord.py version 2.0

Expected:
The role being given to the user

Result:
Nothing happens

Comment: Please [edit] your post to trim the code down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearently I passed custom_id with an int, but it needs a str.